# git pull origin develop vs git merge

Tags: git

I've checked out a feature to start to work; but I wanted to update it with the last develop. But I made a mistake, instead of 'git rebase develop' I did 'git pull origin develop' , and I see that a merge occurred.  Is that ok? I can go on, it's similar to to 'git rebase' or 'git merge develop'?

```
$git checkout feature/migration
Branch 'feature/migration' set up to track remote branch 'feature/migration' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'feature/migration'


$git pull origin develop
From https://github.com/xxx
 * branch              develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging web/package.json
Auto-merging package.json
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 api/src/entity/User.ts            |  8 ++++++ ... more
```

I did

```
git reset --hard  619c69ae
```

log BEFORE reset

```
$git lg1
*   18ee4066 - (2 minutes ago) Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/proj into feature/migration - Dave (HEAD -> feature/migration)
|\  
| *   619c69ae - (16 hours ago) Merge branch 'release/3.1.64' into develop - Dave (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop)
| |\  
* | | e8491f6e - (3 days ago) fix delete index - Dave (origin/feature/migration)
```

glog AFTER reset

```
*   619c69ae - (16 hours ago) Merge branch 'release/3.1.64' into develop - Dave (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, origin/HEAD, feature/migration)
|\  
| | *   eaa8f62a - (16 hours ago) Merge branch 'release/3.1.64' - Dave (tag: 3.1.64, origin/master, master)
| | |\  
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * | 2dda35ad - (16 hours ago) release 3.1.64 - Dave
|/ /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ok to proceed with your development.
But anyway main diffs between `rebase` and `merge` are

- You get a much cleaner project history from `rebase` by eliminating unnessasary merge commits and re-writing your history in a liner order.

If you still wants to go back and try `rebase` then,

Undo merge

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Then rebase

```
git rebase develop
```

Comment: I've did a :  git reset --hard  619c69ae, I've update my question , can you check if is ok too?

Comment: Git saves the original HEAD pointer in a variable called ORIG_HEAD before doing dangerous operations, so it is simple to recover your branch at the state before the rebase/merge. just try `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`

Comment: i see you have reset everything into the commit `619c69ae`.Which means you are now just got back to your initial state(state before you `git pull origin develop`).It should OK for you to do `git rebase develop` now.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK. We can roughly say `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`.

Also, sometimes `git rebase` [can cause disasters](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#_rebase_peril), so you may consider using merge rather than rebase.

However, `git rebase` vs `git merge` can be [different point of view for histories](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#_rebase_vs_merge).

Comment: can you check my log if all is ok?